# Holding two different versions of the same spring bean in the same application context

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring based application that uses beans to describe the metadata of certain entities. As my application grows, the metadata also changes.

Upon a new release of my application, I want to sustain the old bean definition together with the new one and to make them available to the program.

My original idea was to add a new property to the bean definition called 'Version'. Its value will correspond correspond to a release version. Thus if I want to change the metadata definition of one of the entities, I copy paste the old definition, make the required changes (e.g. add a field) and update the version field.

In code I can easily filter the beans by their version.

**The problem**:

Naturally, Spring will not allow me to have two beans with the same id (it does not know that I actually can disambiguate by version). It seems that instead of adding a new property to the bean definition, I need to encode the version in its name.

Is this the proper way to do it in Spring (I did not find any OOTB support for this)? Are there any other patterns that solve this issue?

Comment: I don't get all of what you are trying to do so this may be irrelevant but an inheritance of your first "version" of your bean and instantiating father and son wouldn't solve the case ?

Comment: @benzonico, No. Because I do not necessarily want to inherit everything. e.g. I may want to remove fields  or to split fields (which is equivalent to remove and add)

Comment: @Vitaliy I have the same exact problem. Did you manage to get that working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two beans of the same type *and* the same name at the same time. You could include a version suffix in the bean name, but this is likely to break some of your `@Autowired` injections.

Spring profiles (introduced in 3.1) are a way to quickly switch between alternative context configurations, but activating two of them at the same time may again lead to conflicts.